# True False Converging and Diverging Questions

Tags: calculus, divergence-operator

could I please get help with the following true/false questions? I have been trying to use the theorems in my textbook, but just don't feel too sure on where I'm at...

1. (infinity upper bound, k=1 on the bottom)If ∑ak converges, then when k=10 it also converges. I said TRUE.
2. (infinity upper bound, k=1 on the bottom)If ∑ak diverges, then when k=10 it also diverges. I said TRUE.
3. If just ∑ak converges, then ∑(ak+.00001) also converges (I'm not sure)
4. If ∑p^k diverges, then ∑(p+.001)^k diverges, for a fixed real number p. True? (not sure)
5. If ∑k^-p converges, then ∑k^(-p+.001) converges. Again I feel like this is TRUE.
6. If limit as k approaches infinity ak=0, then ∑ak converges. True (I feel fairly confident on this one)

Thank you to all who respond!!

Comment: For $6$, you probably have seen a theorem stating that $\sum a_k$ converges implies $a_k\to 0$ (which is kind of obvious, since otherwise you would be summing infinitely many "big" numbers...). But $6$ is actually stating the converse, and usually converse theorems are not automatically true. Think about $\sum_{n\ge 1} 1/n$...

Comment: For 1 and 2, note that what determines convergence of divergence is the behavior of the "tail" of the series, i.e, what happens from some value of $k$ on (the sum of any finite number of terms of the series is finite, so convergence/divergence is determined by the sum of the rest of the terms. So you are correct on these.

Comment: For 3, what happens when you add a lot of terms 0.00001? Doesn't the sum get very large eventually? So, ... . Angelo already commented on 6. For 5, what do you know about the series $\sum 1/k^p?$ This is a $p$-series, and has a well-known condition on $p$ to determine convergence. If a given $p$ satisfies this condition, does $p-0.001$ necessarily satisfy the condition? For 4, I would suggest the root test and proceed as in 5.